# Trainable weight for TensorFlow sequence_loss_by_example()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to have a trainable weight in `seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example()`, e.g.

```
w = tf.get_variable("w", [batch_size*num_steps])
loss = seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example([logits_1],
            [tf.reshape(self._targets, [-1])],
            w,vocab_size_all)
```

However, running this code gives me the following error:

```
seq2seq.py, line 654, in sequence_loss_by_example
if len(targets) != len(logits) or len(weights) != len(logits):
```

According to the docstring for this function in `seq2seq.py`:

```
weights: list of 1D batch-sized float-Tensors of the same length as logits.
```

It requires a "Tensor", but I want to pass a `tf.Variable`. Is there a way to have trainable weights in this function?

Comment: could you include the full traceback (error) message?

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, ok, will do that next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TensorFlow a [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable) can be used anywhere a [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor) (of the same element type and shape) is expected.

Therefore, it you want to define a trainable weight, you can pass a list of `tf.Variable` objects as the `weights` argument to [`seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/13ea3ca91ba5aecab6f21acc14b9cb6a9afa8630/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L814). For example, you could do the following:

```
# Defines a list of `num_steps` variables, each 1-D with length `batch_size`.
weights = [tf.get_variable("w", [batch_size]) for _ in range(num_steps)]

loss = seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example([logits_1, ..., logits_n],
                                        [targets_1, ..., targets_n],
                                        weights,
                                        vocab_size_all)
```